# Using Python3 GExiv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, metadata

I'm trying to use GExiv2 to handle metadata for a application I'm writing, but I'm having issues with it. According to the python example at [GExiv2's home page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2/PythonSupport) the expression is:

```
#example
exiv = GExiv2.Metadata('IMAGE FILE')
#my case
exif = GExiv2.Metadata('/home/kimothy/Temp/vuescan/Scan-140102-0001.jpg')
```

This results in the following error

```
[kimothy@localhost Medium Format]$ python3 multi/metadata.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "multi/metadata.py", line 50, in <module>
exif = GExiv2.Metadata('/home/kimothy/Temp/vuescan/Scan-140102-0001.jpg')
TypeError: GObject.__init__() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

I'm puzzled by the fact that the error message states that GExiv2.Metadata() takes exactly zero arguments. Has GExiv2 changed in the latest versions, or have I done something wrong?

Python Version: 3.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be a known (and pretty recent) bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gexiv2/+bug/1277894

As explained in the bug report, there's a workaround for python 3 until the bug it's fixed:

```
from gi.repository.GExiv2 import Metadata 

m = Metadata()
m.open_path('my_image.png')
```